# angular2 2.0.0-rc.1 RouteConfig decorator seems to have disappeared ...?

Tags: angular, routeconfig

@RouteConfig seems to have disappeared from angular2 2.0.0-rc.1, @RouteConfig is in the @angular/router-deprecated package, idem on the api documented on the site,

So what is the proper way to defines routes now?

Answer (score 7):

Check the changlog on github: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

The router you're using is deprecated and now referred to as `router-deprecated` package that need to be installed separately for backward compatibility. Instead of `RouteConfig` use the new `Routes` imported from '@angular/router' (aka new router).

It's still missing a few features, such as route name and data, but they might add those in future.

Comment: i might not using routes the proper way, but those 2 changes (name and data) are quite usefull ... let's go on !!

Comment: just for fun : "...One caveat is that we could no more refer to a route by name ..."                                    ...I agree...

Comment: I've asked them to put `data` back since sometimes you don't want to pass data via URL but behind the scene. Or provide another way for doing that: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8515

Comment: Route name still missing?